# Sending XML post request using API

Tags: php, xml, api, curl, cloud

I am attempting to make an xml post request which hit the other server url and post xml data their but the code not working for me here is my code

```
if ($mail->send()) {
        $URL = "server link api based";

        $ch = curl_init($URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml','Content-Length:     ' . strlen($xml)));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
      //  echo $output;
        if ($output) {
            echo "1";
        } else {
            echo "2";
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

XML format of data here is the code of xml format

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <data>
    <lead>
       <key>YaskjdfweuYksdlksid....</key>
    <leadgroup>.....</leadgroup>
    <site>.....</site>
    <introducer>0</introducer>

    <source>FDH Quick submission</source>
    <medium>FDH Quick submission</medium>

          <firstname>' . $firstName . '</firstname>
          <lastname>' . $lastName . '</lastname>
          <email>' . $userEmail . '</email>
          <postcode>' . $postCode . '</postcode>
          <contactphone>Yes</contactphone>
          <phone1>' . $userPhoneNo . '</phone1>
   </lead>
</data>';
```

Comment: What "not working" means to you?

Comment: Please add more details, the code doesn't send, sends incorrect, etc. Also I don't think you `catch` without first `try`ing. Might also want to use htmlspecialchars on those variables so special characters are encoded correctly.

Comment: Not working means, when i want to post the data on other portal then the data doesnot appear there, no error in code because i also added me email with this cod to test to recieve the the templete based email but email working fine no error in email no error in xml but one issue with that code the data not going on that server where i want to post, code runing successfuly but not putting data to the server

Answer (score 1):

1 possible issue is that you're not escaping your strings as you insert them in your XML, which might leave you with a corrupt XML file (eg, `&` must be escaped as `&amp;`, `<` must become `&lt;`, `'` must become `&apos;`, and so on)

you can xml-encode strings with this function:

```
function xml_esacpe(string $str, string $charset = 'UTF-8'): string {
    if (! strlen ( $str )) {
        return "";
    }
    $ret = htmlspecialchars ( $str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED | ENT_XML1, $charset, true );
    if (! strlen ( $ret )) {
        throw new Exception ( "failed to xml-encode input! (most likely wrong charset or corrupted input)" );
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

furthermore, you can verify that your XML is valid by doing `$isValidXML=@((new DOMDocument())->loadXML($xml));`  - it will now be true if the xml is valid, or false if the xml is invalid. - is the xml you're sending actually valid xml?

but in any case, you must elaborate what you mean by `the code not working for me` - *how* is it not working?

Comment: Can we test xml format  on testing website,  any link to test the posting data using api from that server

Comment: @adilamin i don't know of any pre-made website for testing, but you can easily create 1 for yourself. it would literally be `<?php echo ((@(new DOMDocument())->loadXML($_POST['XML']??'')) ? '1':'0');` - if you add that code to a web server, the page will say `1` if the posted XML is valid, or `0` if the xml is invalid..

Comment: @hanshenrik DUDE YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER!!! ... I've spent 30 hours chasing my tail, and all it was - invalid XML... Thank you so so much!!!